# x-wp-nonce is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: rest-api, api, headers, domain

I would like my dev server on `http://localhost:8080` to work with my wordpress install's rest api, of which the api base url is at `http://localhost/wptest2/index.php/wp-json/` I am currently getting the title error when I try to make requests through the dev server:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/wptest2/index.php/wp-
json/plugin/load?limit=10&offset=0'
 from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked
 by CORS policy: Request header field x-wp-nonce is not
 allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

In my plugin's entry file I have the following:

```
function add_cors_http_header() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . 'add_cors_http_header');
```

I thought this would enable cross domain requests but apparently it is not enough, at least for `x-wp-nonce`.

Is there anything more that can be done to enable the dev server to accept my nonce header?

**Update**

There is no change after adding `Access-Control-Allow-Headers : *` to the cors setting function:

```
function add_cors_http_header() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
  header("Access-Control-Max-Age: *");
}
```

**Update 2**

Here is the OPTIONS request:

[image: Options Request]

**Update 3**

Now the X-WP-Nonce header is set to append instead of replace, the function is hooked to rest_pre_serve_request, and it's added as a filter instead of action:

```
function add_cors_http_header() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-WP-Nonce", false);
}
add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . 'add_cors_http_header');
```

I now get `403 Forbidden`

I have copied the cookie name `wordpress_logged_in_69cb7e12fd<removed>` and its value to the dev server domain at `localhost:8080` but this does not change the response.

**Update 4**

The nonce I use is freshly copied from my wordpress session in another tab that creates the nonce and localizes it into the react.js app. This React.js script file is built using `npm run build` and hooked to admin_footer. It is a slightly older version of the script.

The newest React.js script is in another tab on `localhost:8080` The nonce is put into React manually and sent as a request like so:

```
// globals.js
// this file is loaded by index.jsx, the top level component file

global.clientNonce = "5d6352af1d";


// in Chrome browser, tab open to localhost:8080
console.log(clientNonce) // "5d6352af1d"


// ViewCoupons.jsx, back in the IDE
// this file is loaded by index.jsx. clientNonce is passed down as a prop

const fetchAllCoupons = async (limit, offset) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${apiBaseUrl}/${namepaceAndVersion}/load?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`, {
        method : 'get'
        , headers : {
          'X-WP-Nonce' : clientNonce
        }
      });
      let data = await response.json();

      if (data && 'error' in data) {
        setSnackbarMessage(data.error)
      }

      return data;
    }
    catch (e) {
      // console.log(e, `=====error=====`);
      throw e;
    }
  };
```

[image: 2nd request]

[image: cookies]

Comment: The error message mentions [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers): this is a whitelist so you do need this. There are others e.g. Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Max-Age you should consider adding too - I can't remember if they're mandatory or not.

Comment: @Rup Thanks, I've set them both to `*` but the issue remains the same

Comment: OK: maybe the headers aren't getting added to the OPTIONS response? Can you look for a CORS pre-flight check (i.e. an OPTIONS request) in your browser's debug tools and check what request and response headers you're getting?

Comment: Ok, I have posted the full OPTIONS request above. It looks like the response headers were correctly added

Comment: The `init` hook is too early - WordPress [overwrites](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_server/serve_request/#source) the header later. Try with the [`rest_pre_serve_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_serve_request/) filter (but make sure to `return` the first function parameter) - e.g. `header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-WP-Nonce', false );`

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm getting `403 Forbidden` now which I take as a good sign. Should it work after i copy the user cookie over or is this an indication of some other issue?

Comment: I have copied the cookie wordpress_logged_in_<rest removed> along with its value, from my wordpress install's domain over to the React.js dev server domain `localhost:8080`. But I'm still getting 403 Forbidden on the above requests

Comment: Did you send the proper `X-WP-Nonce` value? Is it actually still valid for the user? Can you post a screenshot of the request and response? And what's the code you use for making the request?

Comment: Also, although this may *not* fix the issue, you should return the *first* parameter passed to your `add_cors_http_header` function - `function add_cors_http_header( $served ) { /* ... */ return $served; }`

Comment: Ok, I have added the argument and returned it after the `header()` statements. Please see update 4 above for the other information.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but instead of trying hard to send the cookie nonce, and as I've said, consider using an authentication plugin which doesn't require you to use the `X-WP-Nonce` header or the `_wpnonce` query.

Comment: Isn't the origin different because the wp install is on port 80 vs port 8080 for the dev server? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, I didn't really notice the ports. But anyway, I deleted that comment and once again, try - or go with - an authentication plugin. That should work and should answer your other [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/348553). Cheers.